# Why button changes color when I click or hover on it? Xaml windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml

I have created a button using XAML and have defined some simple properties for it.

```
<Button  Name="btnNext" Grid.Row="1"  Content="PARA" Width="200" Grid.Column="1" Background="#FF2D2D2D" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="40" Height="380" BorderThickness="0"  />
```

It happens that when I click on the button or put the mouse over, it changes color. 
I have tried to escape this behaviour in the btnNext_Click method but it does not affect anything.

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;

    if (button != null)
    {
        button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(hexToColorConvertor("#FF2D2D2D"));
        START_POINT += (uint)NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS1;
        ReadFile(START_POINT);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Um, you "created" a button? What you're describing is expected behavior provided by the `Style` template of `TargetType` `Button`, what are you working with specifically? WPF/WP/SL, etc? It's just a matter of either editing the template or overriding the defaults. It's generally a good idea to investigate/learning how something works before trying to write code behind to counter it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XAML, button have default style for different states like Normal, MouseOver, Pressed etc..
Whenever button moves from one state to another, it changes its look using default style obviously. You can find more information related to default style [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Now, If you want to override this default behavior, you can do it easily with Expression-blend. More of this can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903963%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613598%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hope this information will help you.. :)